# Accessing Values after Sorting Vector

Tags: c++, sorting

I sort data elements according to the index of the sorted list. When I need to sort the data a second or third time, I need the original order of the data back each time to sort again. How can I access values stored in original order again?

```
decltype(m_data) new_m_datalast;
vector<int> m_newOrder;


for(int i=0; i< (int) m_data.size(); ++i)
    new_m_datalast.push_back(std::move(m_data[m_newOrder[i]]));

m_data = new_m_datalast;
```

UPDATE

```
 void Canvas::SetSortedOrder(std::vector<int> idxs)
  {
   m_newAxesOrder.clear();
   m_newAxesOrder = idxs;

   m_minmaxdata.clear();
   QString filename(":/simdata/minmax.csv");
   m_minmax = ReadCSV(filename);

  decltype(m_data) new_m_data;
  decltype(m_minmaxdata) new_m_minmaxdata;

  for(int i=0; i< (int) m_data.size(); ++i)
    new_m_data.push_back(std::move(m_data[m_newAxesOrder[i]]));

  for(int i=0; i< (int) m_minmaxdata.size(); ++i)
    new_m_minmax.push_back(std::move(m_minmax[m_newAxesOrder[i]]));

   m_data = new_m_data;
   m_minmax = new_m_minmax;
 }
```

Comment: You will need to make a copy before you sort.  But if you're going to sort the data again, why do you need it in its original order?

Comment: That doesn't make any sence *unless* you rely on stable sorts. If *not*, you can just sort again with new criteria, forgetting about original order, it will be thrown over anyway.

Comment: Or, you can make an index vector (initialized as 1, 2, ... N) and apply the same transformations to that during sorting as are applied to the main vector. Then you have a correspondence between the old & new position. It's fiddly though, because you need a proxy type to use this with `std::sort`.

Comment: @paul Because I have another vector that uses original order, working together with the data I sort. Can you give me an example of how to copy?

Comment: `auto copy_of_vector = original_vector;`

Comment: Similar to @Useless 's proposition: Store the index right together with data, i. e. `std::vector<std::pair<Data, unsigned int>>` instead of `std::vector<Data>`. There are even [comparisons](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) available for `std::pair` provided the respective elements are comparable, too.

Comment: @useless When I sort a second time, I cannot access the value in the same order, e.g. data[0] now stores data[5].

Comment: Which implies `index[0] = 5`, so you know where that element was originally.

Comment: @Cece So you need *stable* sorting, based on original order? Or do you need *both* original and sorted order *in parallel* – accessing the original vector by index or iterating over it?

Comment: @Useless Could be the other lookup is more relevant, not to lookup origin by current position, but to lookup current position by origin? Well, would be easy to produce with another iteration...

Comment: Sorry, im confused. I have two vectors: one is data and the other is for min-max values that I read from a file each time. Then I sort both first time which is fine. When I sort a second time, min-max is sorted from the original order but data now have a different order. That's why they are not matching

Comment: Your question doesn't say anything about a second vector of min-max values, and it's still unclear _why_ you need the "original order of the data back to sort again". Can you clarify your question?

Comment: I updated the code by adding min-max part too

Answer (score 5):

If you need to sort a lot of times and access original data later, I suggest you to use [tag sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tag-sort/). Here is a small C++ example:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<size_t> tag_sort(const std::vector<T>& arr) {
    std::vector<size_t> tag(arr.size());
    std::iota(tag.begin(), tag.end(), 1);

    std::sort(tag.begin(), tag.end(), [&arr](auto a, auto b) { return arr[a] < arr[b]; });

    return tag;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> arr = {5, 7, 2, 5, 9, 6, 1};

    auto tag = tag_sort(arr);

    for (auto v : tag) 
        std::cout << v << " ";

    std::cout << "\nsorted data:\n";

    for (auto v : tag) 
        std::cout << arr[v];

    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

As you see, you can access original data in `arr`, and use `tag` vector to use sorted data.

Tag sort is mainly used when switching elements by moving/copying is very expensive. But I think it is a good approach for your problem too.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure this way isn't the best. But I do it anyway. I make a `vector<pair<int,int>> v` and I put the data I want to sort in `first` like: `v[i].first = data` and their indices in `second` like:`v[i].second = i` and I sort the vector or process it as I like. And I can access its original order any time I need.

Note: using `sort(v.begin(),v.end())` will sort by `first` of the pair by default without the need to make a compare function.